# How to call function from one function in WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, filter, hook

How can I call specific function in plugin in admin page.
I am submitting a form in WordPress plugin. On submitting I want to check validity of key which is entered in the form. I have a function which checkes the validity of the key. I want to call that function from the function of the form. 
I have tried few things but it gives me error of 
Using $this when not in object context

Here is my code

```
class WP_Cms_Plugin{

    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'cms_options_panel' ));
    }

    function cms_options_panel() {
        add_menu_page('CMS', 'Cms', 'manage_options', 'cms-dashboard', array(__CLASS__,'cms_setting_form'), 'dashicons-building');
    }

    function cms_setting_form() 
    {

        if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
        {
          $secret_key = $_POST['project_secret_key'];
          if($secret_key=='' || empty($secret_key))
          {
            $error['project_secret_key'] = 'Please enter Secret Key.';
          }
          if(empty($error)){
                call to cms_check_key();
                echo "Key validated successfully";
          } 
          else 
          {
                echo "Please use proper Key";
          }
        }
        ?>
      <form method="post">
            <div>Secret Key</div>
            <input type="text" name="project_secret_key" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('cms_secret_key') ); ?>" required/>
        <?php submit_button('Submit','primary','btn_submit'); ?>
      </form>

        <?php 
    }

    function cms_check_key($secret_key)
    {
        code to check validity
    }
}
$cmsservice = new WP_Cms_Plugin();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your callable specifies using the `WP_Cms_Plugin` class and not an instance of it (object).

#### Either change your `cms_options_panel` function to:

```
add_menu_page('CMS', 'Cms', 'manage_options', 'cms-dashboard', array($this,'cms_setting_form'), 'dashicons-building');
```

(replace `__CLASS__` with `$this`)

#### Or try a static function

```
static function cms_check_key($secret_key)
```

and then call `WP_Cms_Plugin::cms_check_key($secret_key)` from the form.

[PHP Static Keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)